# sharepoint checkbox validation in SPDesigner

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am using sharepoint Office Designer 2007, to validate a checkbox (terms and conditions) through JavaScript.

Details:

I have created a custom list and in the custom there is a field called terms and conditions.
I have inserted the custom list in new .aspx page. I have changed the  sharepoint checkbox to asp checkbox.

And I am trying to validate it through client validation function by aspx custom validator.
My code looks like

```
function TermsValidate(sender, args)
{
    args.Isvalid=documnent.getelementById("ff2_1").checked);
}
```

The validation looks like it triggering but object required error comes up.

Did any one face or come across this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks, I have figured out the way to access the checkbox control. run the code and go to viewsource from the browser get the id generated by the browser on the client.

And validate it thru the custom validator function.

Thanks everyone who tried to help me.